Oxidation of tertbutanol alcohol with potassium permanganate
When I added turtbutanol into my test tube that had KMNO4 in it, it reacted and turned to a yellow color. The thing that I’m most confused on is, tertiary alcohols don’t normally react with KMNO4.. so how come mine did?

In case  this question reopen: The title should be change to "Oxidation of tert-butanol with potassium permanganate." Because "tertbutanol alcohol " does not make any sense.
